# Sending Windows Event Logs from Agent to Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. The system stats send fine, but the event logs don't. The count its trying to send is correct it just doesn't seem to be received correctly. Not sure where I am going wrong. I have logging on both sides but its doesn't seem to hit the server correctly. The logging stats it Received Event Logs, but doesn't save them to the database for some weird reason. Maybe I have just been looking at this too long and its something stupid...

Server

```
public async Task UpdateLogs(List<EventLogEntryModel> eventLogs)
    {
       _logger.LogInformation("Received Event Logs");

        try
        {
            foreach (var log in eventLogs)
            {
               // _logger.LogInformation($"Event ID: {log.EventID}, Entry Type: {log.EntryType}, Message: {log.Message}");
                _context.EventLogs.Add(log);

            }
        
          }

        catch (Exception ex) // Catching exceptions to log errors
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while updating stats."); // Logging the error
            throw; 
        }
    }
```

Client

```
  protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        await ConnectWithRetryAsync(stoppingToken);

        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
               List<EventLogEntryModel> eventLogs = CollectEventLogs("Application");
                var (cpuUsage, totalRam, diskSpace) = CollectSystemStats();

                if (DateTime.Now.Minute % 1 == 0)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation($"Sending Information: CPU {cpuUsage}, Ram {totalRam}, Disk {diskSpace}");

                    var systemStats = new SystemStats
                    {
                        CpuUsage = cpuUsage,
                        RamUsage = totalRam,
                        DiskSpace = diskSpace
                    };

 
                     


                    await _connection.InvokeAsync("UpdateStats", systemStats);

                    _logger.LogInformation($"Sending {eventLogs.Count} logs to the server.");


                    await _connection.InvokeAsync("UpdateLogs", eventLogs);
                }
                // Check-in
                // await _connection.InvokeAsync("CheckIn", "yourAgentId");

                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3), stoppingToken);

            }
            catch (HubException ex)
            {
                // Log or handle the exception as needed
                Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
 private List<EventLogEntryModel> CollectEventLogs(string logName)
    {
        List<EventLogEntryModel> eventLogsList = new List<EventLogEntryModel>();
     
    try
        {
            EventLog eventLog = new EventLog(logName);
            int count = 0; // Counter for limiting the number of logs
            foreach (EventLogEntry entry in eventLog.Entries)
            {
                if (count >= 10) // Stop after adding 10 entries
                    break;

                eventLogsList.Add(new EventLogEntryModel
                {
                    EntryType = entry.EntryType.ToString(),
                    EventID = entry.EventID,
                    Message = entry.Message,
                    // ... other properties
                });
                count++;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle exceptions appropriately
            _logger.LogError($"An error occurred while collecting event logs: {ex.Message}");
        }

        return eventLogsList;
    }
```

Comment: Are you calling `_context.SaveChanges()`. Since in this code you are just adding the logs to the context.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I guess I was staring at it too long missing the obvious!